# Not showing LinearLayout style in a ListView's header

Tags: android, android-layout, header, android-listview, styles

I have a `ListView` with a header. In this header a `LinearLayout` has a predefined style. The thing is that this layout doesn't show that style.

The code of the header:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?blueHardBackground"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerCiudad"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/spinnerCategoria"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textNombreElemento"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="6pt"
            android:typeface="serif" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/botonFiltrar"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:contentDescription="Mostrar"
            android:src="@drawable/buscar_n" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/capaNumResultados"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textNumResultados"
            style="?textRegular"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

It should appear center in blue with round corners, but it's shown transparent with no style, and on the left.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want

```
style="?style/blueHardBackground">
```

in your `LinearLayout` instead of

```
style="?blueHardBackground">
```

you are missing the `style` after the "?" to tell the xml where to look for the name `blueHardBackground`

***[This Link in the Docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)***
explains about accessing `resources`

Comment: I updated my answer to show you the difference. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your effort. If I put what you say it says: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'style' with value '?style/blueHardBackground'). There must be something wrong. The thing is that I can't center or change any parameter.

Comment: You apparently don't have `blueHardBackground` added as a `resource`. Also, just a bit of advice, your `layout` would probably be easier and more efficient as a `RelativeLayout` since you have multiple `LinearLayout`s with only one child

Comment: Yes I have it, in fact, there are other layers that they get the style. I tried changing to relative... but it didn't work

Comment: Just changing to `RelativeLayout` won't solve the problem. I meant to do that and remove the `LinearLayout`s that aren't needed. It will take a little more time but will probably benefit you in the long run. You want the root layout centered? Try posting a picture of your desired result and it will be easier to help but I still suggest reworking it with a `RelativeLayout`